# Round Python list items each with diffrent decimal places

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, rounding

I use Python 3.6.4

I have a class in which I calculate a bunch of attributes. I have to round all these to different decimal places and some of them can be None.

**Example:**

Let's assume I have the following attributes , values, decimal places

```
a, 1.155 , 0
b, 1.123 , 2
c, None  , 1
...
```

what I need as a result is

```
a= 1.2
b= 1.23
c= None
...
```

**Trivial Solution**

I go for every Attribute and round it like

```
if attribute is not None:
    attribute = round(attribute, decimal_places)
```

but I have too much attributes.

**What I tried:**

I made a list of tuples (attribute, decimal_places). Like this:

```
attributes_decimal_places =  [
            (self.a, 0),
            (self.b, 2),
            (self.c, 1),
]
```

On this list I can run the following command which gives me the correct rounded values but I am not able to save this resultvalues in the attributes

```
solution = [round(x[0], x[1]) if isinstance(x[0], float) else x[0] for x in attributes_decimal_points]
```

**Question:**

How do I get the rounded values into the attributes and not in a list?

**Solution:**

Thanks to everyone who answered. A solution which works fine for me:

```
    attributes_decimal_points = [
        (self.a, "a", 1),
        (self.b, "b", 2),
        (self.c, "c", 3)
    ]

    for attribute in attributes_decimal_points:
        if attribute[0] is None:
            continue
        else:
            setattr(self, attribute[1], round(attribute[0], attribute[2]))
```

Comment: what's the datatype of your input?

Comment: What do you mean by "too many attributes"? Are you facing issues with efficiency? You will have to iterate over your data set no matter what you try.

Comment: all attribute values are float or None type. The decimal_places are integer >= 0. Efficiency is not a problem. I just do not want to repeat my code for 100 attributes with the trivial solution. Yes I want to iterate over it but I cant use different decimal places for each item

Comment: You can use "setattr(<object>, <attribute_name>, <value>)" to make object's attributes dynamic

Comment: `attribute[0] = round(attribute[0], attribute[2])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dictionary:

```
    solution = {}
    for x in attributes_decimal_points:
        if isinstance(x[0], float):
            solution.update({x[0]: round(x[0], x[1])})
        else:
            solution.update({x[0]: x[1]})
```

That way you can get the attributes by their names.

Comment: when I use this with attributes_decimal_places  list from my opening post I get the following result like: 1.155: 1.2, 1.123: 1.12 but the instance attributes stay the same

Comment: yes because now the results are in the `solution` variable. I don't know what is `the instance` in your case but you have the rounded values in the `solution` variable and you should just map them to your `instance` values...